# IPv6 and Privacy Extensions in Linux not working as expected with dhcpv6

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, privacy, nfs

I'm trying to setup my desktop to generate and use temporary address for IPv6, but no matter what I'm doing it is not working.
My internet router is managed by my provider, so I can not influence the router advertisement. AdvManagedFlag and AdvOtherConfigFlag are both set to "on" and an address is provided via dhcpv6. I have set with sysctl (and settings are applied):

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.all.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.all.temp_valid_lft = 86600
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.temp_valid_lft = 86600
```

Altough I have a Debian system I use for network configuration either NetworkManager or systemd-networkd. Here is my systemd config:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
#DHCP=yes
DHCP=ipv6
Address=192.168.114.10/24
Address=fd3e:64c2:2817:d97e::a/64
Gateway=192.168.114.1
DNS=192.168.114.3
DNS=fd3e:64c2:2817:d97e::3
DNSSEC=false
DNSSECNegativeTrustAnchors=tr-home.de
Domains=tr-home.de ~.
# overrides setting via sysctl
IPv6PrivacyExtensions=kernel
ManageTemporaryAddress=true
IPv6AcceptRA=true
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
IPv6LinkLocalAddressGenerationMode=eui64

[IPv6AcceptRA]
UseDNS=false
Token=eui64

[DHCPv6]
UseDNS=false
```

With those settings no tempaddr is generated at all.

As an alternative I use NetworkManager. I use the setting under tab IPv6 ==> privacy setting it to either "standard" (result is no tempaddr at all) or "temporary addresses preferred" (result is that address generation starts delayed after some minutes but they have a preferred_lft of only 1 second and this way the same address gets reregisterd every second. This leads to problems with avahi constantly registerring an deregistering the address and confusion with chromium as the browser gets confused which address to use and constantly switches.)

I didn't find a setting to tell NetworkManager to use a longer preferred lifetime.

And it seems Linux doesn't like to use privacy extensions in conjunction with dhcpv6 at all.

A second problem I have with privacy extension is related to NFS. I have NFS shares configured based on fixed IP-Addresses. Obviously this can not work with constantly changing temporary addresses. Therefore I use additional IPv6 ULA addresses for internal network traffic. But with privacy extensions enabled temporary addresses are generated for ULA addresses as well. So again my server shares are not useable.

What I need is a setup, where the ULA only on fixed address and global address is generated from router advertisement. I have no problem in having an additional address provided via dhcpv6, so dhcpv6 can be used, but still I want to use a tempaddr.

To me this all looks like a bug in IPv6 setup, but maybe I'm missing something. Is there a way how to setup this correct? Most confusiong to me is, that no tempaddr is generated when dhcpv6 is in use.

RA shown with radvdump:

```
interface wlan0
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        # Note: {Min,Max}RtrAdvInterval cannot be obtained with radvdump
        AdvManagedFlag on;
        AdvOtherConfigFlag on;
        AdvReachableTime 3600000;
        AdvRetransTimer 0;
        AdvCurHopLimit 64;
        AdvDefaultLifetime 1800;
        AdvHomeAgentFlag off;
        AdvDefaultPreference medium;
        AdvSourceLLAddress on;

        RDNSS 2a02:80xx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
        {
                AdvRDNSSLifetime 300;
        }; # End of RDNSS definition


        prefix 2a02:80xx:xxxx:xxxx::/64
        {
                AdvValidLifetime 0;
                AdvPreferredLifetime 0;
                AdvOnLink on;
                AdvAutonomous on;
                AdvRouterAddr off;
        }; # End of prefix definition


        route ::/0
        {
                AdvRoutePreference medium;
                AdvRouteLifetime 1800;
        }; # End of route definition

}; # End of interface definition
```

And yes I need it - I want my privacy.

I don't need dhcpv6, but the ra and dhcp from the router can only be setup by the provider.

I don't see a reason why I can't have a temp address in addition to the one provided via dhcpv6. Android doesn't even use dhcpv6… So at least with Android temp addresses should work already despite the "AdvManagedFlag on" setting.

Comment: Can you show from `rdisc6` the router advertisements that are being received?

Comment: DHCPv6 is the antithesis to client self-management. Do you really need it?

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem is solved. Reason was the incorrect ra from my cable box which was setup by my provider, the culprit is:

```
AdvValidLifetime 0;
AdvPreferredLifetime 0;
```

which leads to continuos regeneration of the ipv6 addresses. I have now valid lifetimes of 12h (43200s).